# Optimizing One-to-Many Joins in Django MySQL ORM for Better Data Presentation

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, join, orm

In Django MySQL ORM, I wanted to join tables with one-to-many relations. Consider a scenario where one user can belong to more than one department. Users and Departments are different entities. Now, if I want to demonstrate the rows as, User columns and department names the user belongs to in a single column as a list. How do I do that most efficiently?

Example:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Output:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'department_names': ['HR', 'IT']},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Alice', 'department_names': ['Finance']}
]
```

I tried this:

```py
queryset = User.objects.values(
    'id',
    'name',
).annotate(
    department_names=Concat(
        'department__name',
        Value(', '),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
).filter(
    department__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

But got this:

```py
<QuerySet [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'department_names': 'HR, '},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'department_names': 'IT, '},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Alice', 'department_names': 'Finance,'}
]>
```

Expecting something this:

```py
<QuerySet [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'department_names': 'HR, IT'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Alice', 'department_names': 'Finance'}
]>
```